# Eclipse browser behaving different than standalone version

Tags: eclipse, internet-explorer, browser, font-face

I'm using the `org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser` for a plugin and would like to dynamically include a font by adding `@font-face` css to head by using javascript.

I'm working on Windows, so eclipse will use the IE engine to render html. But: My solution works great on IE9 when running it in the standalone browser (also in chrome, opera, safari), but not when running it in eclipse.

The javascript is successfully executed, but fonts seem not to be loaded. Are there some security settings I should change on the `Browser` object? I didn't see such a method...

Btw, the font-face urls point to local font files. And `@font-face` works when defining it initially instead of dynamically loading it with JS.